# Unable to deserialize object datatype to given type using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, javascriptserializer

I have classes as below

```
public class ParentClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object Item { get; set; } = new object();
        public Department Dept { get; set; }

    }

    public class ChildClass
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }

    }

    public class Department
    {
        public string DeptName { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm trying to pass data and  deserialize as below

```
    var obj = new ParentClass()
            {
                Name = "Charles",
                Item = new ChildClass()
                {
                    Location = "Chicago"
                },
                Dept = new Department()
                {
                    DeptName = "IT"
                }
            };

            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
            var finalRes = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ParentClass>(json);
```

I'm assigning `ChildClass` to `Item` property which has datatype `object`. While debugging I'm able to see `ChildClass` details as below

[ChildClass details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTCUU.png)

When I serialize it, I have data as below
[Serialized data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULT5C.png)

and when it is deserialized, it has data as below
[Deserialized data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf5Fh.png)

In Deserialized data , getting `Item` property details as `Dictionary` values instead of `ChildClass` type.

How to avoid `object` datatype getting converted to `Dictionary` while deserializing.

I want to assign given type `ChildClass` to `object` property `Item` even after deserializing aswell.

Comment: Well, when you serialize `ParentClass` into json you will lose the type information of the serialized object. And when you try to do the reverse the serializer will see an object (it will have no idea about `ClidClass`) so it will deserialize it into a `Dictionary` which is the default. If you want to keep the data type you may want to convert your `ParentClass` into a generic class that has `Item` property as generic.

Comment: @Eldar, Could you provide some example. It may helpful for me.

Comment: Also I see when I deserialize I'm getting all other types ParentClass and Department except ChildClass. Only object datatype Item getting converted to Dictionary not all.

Answer (score 0):

Using Newtonsoft and the [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) you can do this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var obj = new ParentClass()
{
    Name = "Charles",
    Item = new ChildClass()
    {
        Location = "Chicago"
    },
    Dept = new Department()
    {
        DeptName = "IT"
    }
};
JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializationSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSerializationSetting.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, jsonSerializationSetting);
var finalRes =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentClass>(json, jsonSerializationSetting);
```

If just using JavaScriptSerializer uou can use [SimpleTypeResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.simpletyperesolver?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)
So your code could be like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver());

 var json =  serializer.Serialize(obj);
 var finalRes = serializer.Deserialize<ParentClass>(json);
```

Comment: Actually I'm calling RestApi from Webservice. RestApi endpoint is returning System.Text.Json serialized data to webservice and in my webservice I'm using JavascriptSerializer to deserialize rest api endpoint response. I can't use Newtonsoft. Can you suggest some other alternative while deserializing using Javascriptserializer

Comment: OK, please check the edit I made based on the comments you provided. @SravaniYadav